# Как из QLineEdit дать значение переменной из другого файла?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

У меня есть интерфейс в **main.py**, и файл конфигурации с переменными **config.py**.

**main.ру:**

```py
    import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from menu import Ui_MenuWindow
import config as cf


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

        def openMenu(self):
                self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
                self.ui = Ui_MenuWindow()
                self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
                self.window.show()

        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
                MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
                MainWindow.resize(800, 431)
                MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 39, 42);\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "QLineEdit::focus {\n"
                                         "    border: 2px;\n"
                                         "}\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "")
                self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
                self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
                self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 201, 61))
                self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 51))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Montserrat")
                font.setPointSize(14)
                font.setBold(False)
                font.setItalic(False)
                font.setWeight(10)
                self.label_2.setFont(font)
                self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Montserrat\";\n"
                                           "color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")
                self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
                self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
                self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 481, 61))
                self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                          "border-radius: 10px;")
                self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
                self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
                self.label.setEnabled(True)
                self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 0, 231, 61))
                self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(221, 51))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
                font.setPointSize(22)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.label.setFont(font)
                self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: center;\n"
                                         "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
                self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.label.setObjectName("label")
                self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
                self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 200, 311, 20))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
                self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
                self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "    border: 1px solid  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    color: white;\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 5px;")
                self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
                self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
                self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 361, 21))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setPointSize(9)
                self.label_5.setFont(font)
                self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
                self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 371, 41))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setPointSize(9)
                self.label_6.setFont(font)
                self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
                self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
                self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 240, 311, 20))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
                self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
                self.lineEdit_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "border: 1px solid  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "color: white;\n"
                                              "border-radius: 5px;")
                self.lineEdit_3.setText("")
                self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
                self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.update_data())
                self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 181, 61))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
                font.setPointSize(18)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.pushButton.setFont(font)
                self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                              "    text-align: center;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                              "}\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                              "    text-align: center;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    background-color: #404EED;\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "}\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "QPushButton::focus {\n"
                                              "    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "}")
                self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
                self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 90, 341, 61))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.label_4.setFont(font)
                self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(206, 206, 206);\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
                self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 81, 61))
                self.label_7.setStyleSheet("object-fit: cover;")
                self.label_7.setText("")
                self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"))
                self.label_7.setScaledContents(True)
                self.label_7.setWordWrap(False)
                self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
                MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
                self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
                self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
                self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
                MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
                self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
                self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
                MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

                self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
                QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
                _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
                MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
                self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Setup before start"))
                self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Discord Toolz"))
                self.lineEdit_2.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
                self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Channel ID"))
                self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Changes how fast the messages are posted (in seconds) \n"
                                                              " (Anything under 0.7 tends to break it (┛✧Д✧))┛彡┻━┻ )"))
                self.lineEdit_3.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
                self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
                self.label_4.setText(
                        _translate("MainWindow", "We recommend creating a file that will contain your initial data \n"
                                                 "for running the script. \n"
                                                 "Copying from a file on the desktop is easier than constantly \n"
                                                 "launching the browser"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
                super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
                self.setupUi(self)

                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_data)
                cf.SpamSpeed = self.lineEdit_3.text()
                cf.DiscordChannel = self.lineEdit_2.text()

        def update_data(self):
                cf.SpamSpeed = self.lineEdit_3.text()
                cf.DiscordChannel = self.lineEdit_2.text()
                openMenu()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**config.py**

```
# Basic Config (For all bots)
pythonCommand = "python" # If you have the python command set to something else such as python3
userToken = [] # User Tokens here. example 'token','token' | 'email:pass', 'token'
DiscordChannel = ''  # Channel ID,
SpamSpeed = 120 # Changes how fast the messages are posted. (Anything under 0.7 tends to break it (┛✧Д✧))┛彡┻━┻ )
textRandom = True # if the root has 'text.txt' it will pick a random text line and send it.
textFull = False # Will send everything written in 'text.txt'
discumLog = True # Displays Discums Logs, Very useful for providing more info on what went wrong.

#Server Joiner
useTokenJoin = True
inviteLink = '' # Only the last 6 digits of the invite link https://discord.gg/XXXXXX | Unless you are using email join then just the full URL
autojoinServer = True # Will auto join the inviteLink server if True
useBrowser = 'Firefox' # Chrome | Firefox | Edge (windows only) | Set the browser used for joining the servers.
joinSpeed = 3 # Changes how fast the bot will start the server joiner

#DM Spam
DiscordServer = '' # Server ID (https://i.imgur.com/m06TSEx.png this one)
ScanAllServers = False # (True or False) Instead of using a server ID this will scan all of the users joined servers. 
HeavyScrape = False # (True or False) Use this for servers with a lot of users

#Account Creator
captchaAPI = 'c906c780567d1abd410cdf45c9d0aee3' #2captcha API Key
mailServer = 'pop.gmail.com' # Mail server, pop 3 version. (example = "pop.mail.ru")

#Picture spam
DirPictures = 'pictures' # Picture(s) location, end directory with a double slash.
```

вот ещё menu.py для полноты картины:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from working import Ui_Working
from joiner import Ui_Joiner
from creator import Ui_Creator
from verif import Ui_Verif
import os


class Ui_MenuWindow(object):

    def btnClicked(self):
        self.openWidget()
        os.system('1')

    def openVerif(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Verif()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def openCreator(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Creator()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def openWidget(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_Working()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def openJoimer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Joiner()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, MenuWindow):
        MenuWindow.setObjectName("MenuWindow")
        MenuWindow.resize(800, 431)
        MenuWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 39, 42);\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit::focus {\n"
"    border: 2px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLabel: {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    font: 63 8pt \"Segoe UI Semibold\";\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(114, 137, 218);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    border: 2px solidrgb(114, 137, 218);\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MenuWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 231, 61))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(64, 78, 237);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 231, 61))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: center;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openWidget())
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openWidget())
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 180, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openWidget())
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 140, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 90, 221, 31))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 87 14pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 221, 31))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 87 14pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 260, 221, 31))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 87 14pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openJoimer())
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 300, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openVerif())
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 340, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openCreator())
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        MenuWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MenuWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MenuWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MenuWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MenuWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MenuWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MenuWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MenuWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MenuWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MenuWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Menu"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Text spammer"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Insults spammer"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Insults spammer"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Text spammer"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Servers"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "DM"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Accounts and Joiner"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Joiner (invites)"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Account verifier"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Accounts creator"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MenuWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MenuWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MenuWindow)
    MenuWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И, собственно, вопрос, как мне значение из `LineEdit_2` в **main.py** засунуть значение в `DiscordChannel` который в **config.py**

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать модуль `menu.py`

Comment: сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Я не могу проверить ваш код дальше, потому что вы не опубликовали минимально-воспроизводимый пример. Похоже на то, что у вас еще будут проблемы в дальнейшем.

**q1386456_main.py**

```
import sys
import os                    # +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1386456_menu import Ui_MenuWindow
import q1386456_config as cf

''' эти импорты нужны здесь                         # !!!
from working import Ui_Working                      # +++
from joiner import Ui_Joiner                        # +++
from creator import Ui_Creator                      # +++
from verif import Ui_Verif                          # +++
'''

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
#        def openMenu(self):
#            ...

        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
                MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
                MainWindow.resize(800, 431)
                MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 39, 42);\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "QLineEdit::focus {\n"
                                         "    border: 2px;\n"
                                         "}\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "")
                self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
                self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
                self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 201, 61))
                self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 51))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Montserrat")
                font.setPointSize(14)
                font.setBold(False)
                font.setItalic(False)
                font.setWeight(10)
                self.label_2.setFont(font)
                self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Montserrat\";\n"
                                           "color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")
                self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
                self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
                self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 481, 61))
                self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                          "border-radius: 10px;")
                self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
                self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
                self.label.setEnabled(True)
                self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 0, 231, 61))
                self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(221, 51))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
                font.setPointSize(22)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.label.setFont(font)
                self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: center;\n"
                                         "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
                self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.label.setObjectName("label")
                self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
                self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 200, 311, 20))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
                self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
                self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "    border: 1px solid  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    color: white;\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 5px;")
                self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
                self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
                self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 361, 21))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setPointSize(9)
                self.label_5.setFont(font)
                self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
                self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 371, 41))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setPointSize(9)
                self.label_6.setFont(font)
                self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
                self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
                self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 240, 311, 20))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
                self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
                self.lineEdit_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "border: 1px solid  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "color: white;\n"
                                              "border-radius: 5px;")
                self.lineEdit_3.setText("")
                self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

# ---               self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.update_data())
# !!!
                self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)           # +++ 
                
                self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 181, 61))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
                font.setPointSize(18)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.pushButton.setFont(font)
                self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                              "    text-align: center;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                              "}\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                              "    text-align: center;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    background-color: #404EED;\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "}\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "QPushButton::focus {\n"
                                              "    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "}")
                self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
                self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 90, 341, 61))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.label_4.setFont(font)
                self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(206, 206, 206);\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
                self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 81, 61))
                
# ???                self.label_7.setStyleSheet("object-fit: cover;")
                
                self.label_7.setText("")
                self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"))
                self.label_7.setScaledContents(True)
                self.label_7.setWordWrap(False)
                self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
                MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
                self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
                self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
                self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
                MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
                self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
                self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
                MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
                self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
                QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
                _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
                MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
                self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Setup before start"))
                self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Discord Toolz"))
                self.lineEdit_2.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
                self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Channel ID"))
                self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Changes how fast the messages are posted (in seconds) \n"
                                                              " (Anything under 0.7 tends to break it (┛✧Д✧))┛彡┻━┻ )"))
                self.lineEdit_3.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
                self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
                self.label_4.setText(
                        _translate("MainWindow", "We recommend creating a file that will contain your initial data \n"
                                                 "for running the script. \n"
                                                 "Copying from a file on the desktop is easier than constantly \n"
                                                 "launching the browser"))

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class WindowMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MenuWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowMenu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)        
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.openWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.openWidget)        
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.openWidget)         
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.openJoimer) 
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.openVerif)         
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.openCreator)   

    def btnClicked(self):
        self.openWidget()
        os.system('1')

    def openVerif(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Verif()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def openCreator(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Creator()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def openWidget(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_Working()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def openJoimer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Joiner()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_data)
        self.window = WindowMenu()                         # !!! +++

    def update_data(self):
        spamSpeed = self.lineEdit_3.text()                      # !!! +++
        discordChannel = self.lineEdit_2.text()                 # !!! +++
        
        # !!! +++ тут надо делать какие-то проверки
        if not spamSpeed or not discordChannel:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Внимание', 'Заполните поля ввода.')
            return
    
        cf.SpamSpeed = spamSpeed               # ! - self.lineEdit_3.text()
        cf.DiscordChannel = discordChannel     # ! - self.lineEdit_2.text()
        print(f'cf.SpamSpeed      = {cf.SpamSpeed}')       
        print(f'cf.DiscordChannel = {cf.DiscordChannel}')  
        
#        openMenu()
        self.window.show()                          # !!! +++

'''        
    def openMenu(self):
        ...
'''                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
# -   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
# -   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
# -   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
# -   MainWindow.show()
    w = MainWindow()                            # +++
    w.show()                                    # +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1386456_config.py**

```
# Basic Config (For all bots)
pythonCommand = "python"  
userToken = []            
DiscordChannel = ''
SpamSpeed = 120           
textRandom = True         
textFull = False          
discumLog = True          

#Server Joiner
useTokenJoin = True
inviteLink = ''
autojoinServer = True
useBrowser = 'Firefox'   
joinSpeed = 3  

#DM Spam
DiscordServer = '' 
ScanAllServers = False   
HeavyScrape = False      

#Account Creator
captchaAPI = 'c906c780567d1abd410cdf45c9d0aee3' #2captcha API Key
mailServer = 'pop.gmail.com'                    # Mail server, pop 3 version. (example = "pop.mail.ru")

#Picture spam
DirPictures = 'pictures'                        # Picture(s) location, end directory with a double slash.
```

**q1386456_menu.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''
from working import Ui_Working                           # ???
from joiner import Ui_Joiner                             # ???
from creator import Ui_Creator                           # ???
from verif import Ui_Verif                               # ???
'''

class Ui_MenuWindow(object):
    '''  НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.
    def btnClicked(self):
        ...

    def openVerif(self):
        ...

    def openCreator(self):
        ...

    def openWidget(self):
        ...

    def openJoimer(self):
        ...
    '''

    def setupUi(self, MenuWindow):
        MenuWindow.setObjectName("MenuWindow")
        MenuWindow.resize(800, 431)
        MenuWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 39, 42);\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit::focus {\n"
"    border: 2px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLabel: {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    font: 63 8pt \"Segoe UI Semibold\";\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(114, 137, 218);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    border: 2px solidrgb(114, 137, 218);\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MenuWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 231, 61))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(64, 78, 237);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 231, 61))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: center;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

# ---        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        
# ---       self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openWidget())
# !!!
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)            
        
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        
# ---       self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openWidget())
# !!!
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)        
        
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 180, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        
# ---       self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openWidget())
# !!!
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 140, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 90, 221, 31))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 87 14pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 221, 31))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 87 14pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 260, 221, 31))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"font: 87 14pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        
# ---       self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openJoimer())
# !!!
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 300, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        
# ---       self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openVerif())
# !!!
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 340, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        
# ---       self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openCreator())
# !!!
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)        
        
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 221, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: #404EED;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::focus {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
"    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        MenuWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MenuWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MenuWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MenuWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MenuWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MenuWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MenuWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MenuWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MenuWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MenuWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Menu"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Text spammer"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Insults spammer"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Insults spammer"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Text spammer"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Servers"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "DM"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Accounts and Joiner"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Joiner (invites)"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Account verifier"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MenuWindow", "Accounts creator"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но проблемы и правда появились, но я не понимаю что такое минимально воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: @ТимофейШулимов пожалуйста. Минимальный - это значит, вы публикуете не весь проект, а выделяете из проекта ту часть кода, которая демонстрирует проблему. ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ - это значит, что ваш код копируется и запускается, и демонстрирует проблему, о которой вы пишите.

Comment: хорошо, как будет лучше, если я изменю этот вопрос, или задам новый с таким же названием?

Comment: @ТимофейШулимов не надо изменять текущий вопрос, вам надо создать новый вопрос о новой проблеме.